# String is nil with Parse.com in Swift 1.2

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform

I've searched on many question but I haven't found my answer... Before my code was working pretty well, but it was before Swift 1.2... Could you help me to know why : Could not find an overload for '!=' that accepts the supplied arguments

```
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    UserName.text = user!.username
    UserEmail.text = user!.email
    if (user["phone"] != nil)
    {
        UserPhone.text = user["phone"] as! NSString as String
    }
    else
    {
        UserPhone.text = "Unknow"
    }
```

EDIT : The solution to that problem is simple : just do :

```
        UserPhone.text = PFUser.currentUser()?["phone"] as? String ?? "Unknown"
```

Comment: This solution worked :
`UserPhone.text = PFUser.currentUser()!["phone"] as? String ?? "Unknown"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the nil coalescing operator, `??`. This is exactly what it's designed for:

```
UserPhone.text = user["phone"] ?? "Unknown"
```

That says "If the optional `user["phone"]` is not `nil`, unwrap it's value. If it is `nil`, return the value "Unknown" instead."

Comment: I get  '(@lvalue AnyObject?, StringLiteralConvertible)' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'

Comment: Finally this worked don't know why : 
`UserPhone.text = PFUser.currentUser()!["phone"] as? String ?? "Unknown"`

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
var phoneNS : NSString? 
if let str = user["phone"] as? String {
    phoneNS = NSString(string: str)
}
```

Comment: See my answer using the nil coalescing operator. Much simpler syntax than your answer.

Comment: @DuncanC thats nice, didnt actually know about that one. However I think his user["phone"] is not an optional as it is coming from parse.

Comment: On your new solution i get  '@lvalue AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'String?' on the first line var phone : String? = user["phone"]

Comment: @KewKylyuVacquier ah i thought it was already a string :) now it should work.

Comment: I think Xcode hates me :  'String?' is not convertible to 'String?'

Comment: @KewKylyuVacquier try the updated answer. i have never used parse so I am not 100% sure in what form they respond.

Comment: Din't worked to, but because of the user, don't know why, replacing user by PFUser.currentUser()! is your code worked